# Queries regarding dialogue structure?

Tags: dialogue

I just have a few queries regarding dialogue in a novel, especially if there are several lines of dialogue.

1. When two characters are talking, does each line of speech go on a separate line or can they simply follow after each other?
2. Can a normal sentence follow after a line of speech or would it have to start on a new line?
3. When a new character is first mentioned in a line of speech, is it acceptable to then quickly give a brief description of the character in a sentence before the next line of speech continues the dialogue between the characters?

Comment: In the novel you have read (I am assuming that you have actually read novels) how did you observe these things to be handled? Given what you have seen done in the novels you have read, why do you still have questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has everything to do with your style. How writers structure dialogue varies greatly. However I'll give you a few guidelines that I have observed.

1. It is easier to read if there is a line break between one character talking and the next.
2. A normal sentence can definitely follow a line of speech. This can be very handy for describing the character's body language for instance. In this case it would directly relate to the speech just written, and help prepare for the next character's reaction which would be started on a new line as a new part, so to speak.
3. I would say yes, but be careful to keep it brief so that your reader does not get lost in facts and history while they are trying to keep up with a conversation.